# replacing cubes with images in snake

Tags: python, image, pygame

I'm trying to create a snake game with pick ups that relate to a task I've been given, I've created this code with grids and cubes and need help replacing the cubes with pictures.

I've already tried adding a "pygame.image.load("")" line but was unsuccessful, I've tried changing the code towhat I think would work but what I got in return was a red cube and not an image.

```
import math
import random
import pygame
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import messagebox

class cube(object):
    rows = 20
    w = 500
    def __init__(self,start,dirnx=1,dirny=0,color=(255,0,0)):
        self.pos = start
        self.dirnx = 1
        self.dirny = 0
        self.color = color


    def move(self, dirnx, dirny):
        self.dirnx = dirnx
        self.dirny = dirny
        self.pos = (self.pos[0] + self.dirnx, self.pos[1] + self.dirny)

    def draw(self, surface, eyes=False):
        dis = self.w // self.rows
        i = self.pos[0]
        j = self.pos[1]

        pygame.draw.rect(surface, self.color, (i*dis+1,j*dis+1, dis-2, 
dis-2))
        if eyes:
            centre = dis//2
            radius = 3
            circleMiddle = (i*dis+centre-radius,j*dis+8)
            circleMiddle2 = (i*dis + dis -radius*2, j*dis+8)
            pygame.draw.circle(surface, (0,0,0), circleMiddle, radius)
            pygame.draw.circle(surface, (0,0,0), circleMiddle2, radius)




class snake(object):
    body = []
    turns = {}
    def __init__(self, color, pos):
        self.color = color
        self.head = cube(pos)
        self.body.append(self.head)
        self.dirnx = 0
        self.dirny = 1

    def move(self):
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                pygame.quit()

            keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()

            for key in keys:
                if keys[pygame.K_LEFT]:
                    self.dirnx = -1
                    self.dirny = 0
                    self.turns[self.head.pos[:]] = [self.dirnx, 
self.dirny]

                elif keys[pygame.K_RIGHT]:
                    self.dirnx = 1
                    self.dirny = 0
                    self.turns[self.head.pos[:]] = [self.dirnx, self.dirny]

                elif keys[pygame.K_UP]:
                    self.dirnx = 0
                    self.dirny = -1
                    self.turns[self.head.pos[:]] = [self.dirnx, self.dirny]

                elif keys[pygame.K_DOWN]:
                    self.dirnx = 0
                    self.dirny = 1
                    self.turns[self.head.pos[:]] = [self.dirnx, self.dirny]

        for i, c in enumerate(self.body):
            p = c.pos[:]
            if p in self.turns:
                turn = self.turns[p]
                c.move(turn[0],turn[1])
                if i == len(self.body)-1:
                    self.turns.pop(p)
            else:
                if c.dirnx == -1 and c.pos[0] <= 0: c.pos = (c.rows-1, c.pos[1])
                elif c.dirnx == 1 and c.pos[0] >= c.rows-1: c.pos = (0,c.pos[1])
                elif c.dirny == 1 and c.pos[1] >= c.rows-1: c.pos = (c.pos[0], 0)
                elif c.dirny == -1 and c.pos[1] <= 0: c.pos = (c.pos[0],c.rows-1)
                else: c.move(c.dirnx,c.dirny)


    def reset(self, pos):
        self.head = cube(pos)
        self.body = []
        self.body.append(self.head)
        self.turns = {}
        self.dirnx = 0
        self.dirny = 1


    def addCube(self):
        tail = self.body[-1]
        dx, dy = tail.dirnx, tail.dirny

        if dx == 1 and dy == 0:
            self.body.append(cube((tail.pos[0]-1,tail.pos[1])))
        elif dx == -1 and dy == 0:
            self.body.append(cube((tail.pos[0]+1,tail.pos[1])))
        elif dx == 0 and dy == 1:
            self.body.append(cube((tail.pos[0],tail.pos[1]-1)))
        elif dx == 0 and dy == -1:
            self.body.append(cube((tail.pos[0],tail.pos[1]+1)))

        self.body[-1].dirnx = dx
        self.body[-1].dirny = dy


    def draw(self, surface):
        for i, c in enumerate(self.body):
            if i ==0:
                c.draw(surface, True)
            else:
                c.draw(surface)


def drawGrid(w, rows, surface):
    sizeBtwn = w // rows

    x = 0
    y = 0
    for l in range(rows):
        x = x + sizeBtwn
        y = y + sizeBtwn

        pygame.draw.line(surface, (255,255,255), (x,0),(x,w))
        pygame.draw.line(surface, (255,255,255), (0,y),(w,y))




def redrawWindow(surface):
    global rows, width, s, snack
    surface.fill((0,0,0))
    s.draw(surface)
    snack.draw(surface)
    drawGrid(width,rows, surface)
    pygame.display.update()





def randomSnack(rows, item):

    positions = item.body

    while True:
        x = random.randrange(rows)
        y = random.randrange(rows)
        if len(list(filter(lambda z:z.pos == (x,y), positions))) > 0:
            continue
        else:
            break

    return (x,y)


def message_box(subject, content):
    root = tk.Tk()
    root.attributes("-topmost", True)
    root.withdraw()
    messagebox.showinfo(subject, content)
    try:
        root.destroy()
    except:
        pass


def main():
    global width, rows, s, snack
    width = 500
    rows = 20
    win = pygame.display.set_mode((width, width))
    s = snake((255,0,0), (10,10))
    snack = cube(randomSnack(rows, s), color=(0,255,0))
    flag = True

    clock = pygame.time.Clock()

    while flag:
        pygame.time.delay(50)
        clock.tick(10)
        s.move()
        if s.body[0].pos == snack.pos:
            s.addCube()
            snack = cube(randomSnack(rows, s), color=(0,255,0))


        for x in range(len(s.body)):
            if s.body[x].pos in list(map(lambda z:z.pos,s.body[x+1:])):
                print('Score: ', len(s.body))
                message_box('You Lost!', 'Play again...')
                s.reset((10,10))
                break


        redrawWindow(win)

main()
```

Comment: show code with `pygame.image.load`

Answer (score 1):

Use [`pygame.image.load`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/image.html#pygame.image.load) to load an image to a [`pygame.Surface`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/surface.html) object.
Scale the `pygame.Surface` to the proper size by [`pygame.transform.smoothscale()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/transform.html#pygame.transform.smoothscale):

```py
self.image = pygame.transform.smoothscale(pygame.image.load("myimage.png"), (dis-2, dis-2))
```

Draw the image on the screen by [`pygame.Surface.blit`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/surface.html):

```py
surface.blit(self.image, (i*dis+1,j*dis+1))
```

The image or the name of the image can be a an optional parameter to constrictor of the class `cube`. If the name of the image is given then the image is drawn, else the rectangle is drawn:

e.g.

```py
class cube(object):
    rows = 20
    w = 500
    def __init__(self, start, imagename = None, dirnx=1, dirny=0, color=(255,0,0)):
        self.pos = start
        self.dirnx = 1
        self.dirny = 0
        self.color = color
        try:
            dis = self.w // self.rows
            self.image = pygame.transform.smoothscale(pygame.image.load(imagename), (dis-2, dis-2))
        except: 
            self.image = None

    # [...]

    def draw(self, surface, eyes=False):
        dis = self.w // self.rows
        i = self.pos[0]
        j = self.pos[1]

        if self.image:
            surface.blit(self.image, (i*dis+1,j*dis+1))
        else:
            pygame.draw.rect(surface, self.color, (i*dis+1,j*dis+1, dis-2, dis-2))

        # [...]
```

Comment: thank you, this helped greatly, really appreciate It